# How to run a MERN application

Tags: node.js, npm, mern

My `package.json` file is like below.

```
{
  "name": "machine-shop",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "build": "node ace build --production",
    "start": "node server.js",
    "dev": "node ace serve --watch",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext=.ts",
    "format": "prettier --write ."
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@adonisjs/assembler": "^5.0.0",
    "@babel/core": "^7.14.3",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.13.13",
    "@symfony/webpack-encore": "^1.4.0",
    "@types/node": "^16.3.3",
    "adonis-preset-ts": "^2.1.0",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.2.6",
    "eslint": "^7.27.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-adonis": "^1.3.1",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.4.0",
    "node-pre-gyp": "^0.17.0",
    "pino-pretty": "^5.0.1",
    "postcss": "^8.3.0",
    "postcss-loader": "^5.3.0",
    "prettier": "^2.3.0",
    "sass": "^1.34.0",
    "sass-loader": "^11.1.1",
    "tailwindcss": "^2.1.2",
    "typescript": "~4.2",
    "youch": "^2.2.2",
    "youch-terminal": "^1.1.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@adonisjs/auth": "^8.0.4",
    "@adonisjs/core": "^5.1.0",
    "@adonisjs/lucid": "^14.1.0",
    "@adonisjs/repl": "^3.0.0",
    "@adonisjs/session": "^6.0.0",
    "@adonisjs/shield": "^7.0.0",
    "@adonisjs/view": "^6.0.0",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-decoupled-document": "^28.0.0",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-react": "^3.0.2",
    "@date-io/date-fns": "2.6.1",
    "@formatjs/intl-pluralrules": "1.3.5",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "5.13.0",
    "@manaflair/redux-batch": "1.0.0",
    "@material-ui/core": "4.9.14",
    "@material-ui/icons": "4.9.1",
    "@material-ui/lab": "4.0.0-alpha.53",
    "@material-ui/pickers": "3.2.10",
    "@material-ui/styles": "4.9.14",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.6.1",
    "@tanem/svg-injector": "8.0.50",
    "apexcharts": "^3.27.2",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "axios-mock-adapter": "1.18.1",
    "bootstrap": "4.6.0",
    "camelcase": "^5.2.0",
    "clipboard-copy": "3.1.0",
    "clsx": "1.1.0",
    "cp-cli": "2.0.0",
    "css-mediaquery": "^0.1.2",
    "date-fns": "2.8.1",
    "dotenv": "^10.0.0",
    "dotenv-expand": "5.1.0",
    "downshift": "3.4.2",
    "fg-loadcss": "^3.1.0",
    "formik": "2.1.4",
    "holderjs": "^2.9.9",
    "json2mq": "^0.2.0",
    "luxon": "^1.27.0",
    "material-ui-popup-state": "^1.8.3",
    "mysql": "^2.18.1",
    "object-path": "^0.11.5",
    "phc-argon2": "^1.1.1",
    "phc-bcrypt": "^1.0.7",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "proxy-addr": "^2.0.7",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-app-polyfill": "^1.0.4",
    "react-bootstrap": "1.0.1",
    "react-bootstrap-table-next": "4.0.2",
    "react-bootstrap-table2-paginator": "2.1.2",
    "react-datepicker": "2.16.0",
    "react-dev-utils": "^9.1.0",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-draggable": "4.4.2",
    "react-dropzone": "^11.3.4",
    "react-inlinesvg": "1.2.0",
    "react-intl": "3.6.2",
    "react-is": "16.13.1",
    "react-perfect-scrollbar": "1.5.8",
    "react-portal": "4.2.0",
    "react-redux": "7.1.3",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-select": "3.1.0",
    "react-slick": "^0.28.1",
    "react-swipeable-views": "0.13.9",
    "react-syntax-highlighter": "12.2.1",
    "react-window": "1.8.5",
    "redux": "4.0.5",
    "redux-persist": "6.0.0",
    "redux-saga": "1.1.3",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
    "socicon": "3.0.5",
    "source-map-support": "^0.5.19",
    "sweetalert2": "^11.0.11",
    "yup": "^0.32.9"
  }
}
```

My file structure is like below

[image]

I run `npm start` and below error message.

```
> machine-shop@1.0.0 start /home/foysal/Music/machineshop
> node server.js

/home/foysal/Music/machineshop/server.js:13
import 'reflect-metadata'
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1047:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1097:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1153:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:977:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:877:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:74:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:18:47
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! machine-shop@1.0.0 start: `node server.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the machine-shop@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/foysal/.npm/_logs/2021-07-20T09_16_16_900Z-debug.log
```

[image]

Could any one help me to run this application ?

Comment: what is the node version you are using?

Answer (score 1):

Try putting `"type": "module"` in your `package.json`